# Content disappears when using the <Route> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When ever i add a <**Route**> tag to the code everything just disappears from the screen!

the code is fine i guess! there is no warnings showing!!

the output before adding the <**Route**> tags
[image: a picture before the route tags]

and when i add a <**Route**> tag the output is just not there anymore!!!!

the code before adding the tag:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the code after is really the same but with adding the tags :

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Route></Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And when i added the tags the content disappeared !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you're `package.json` if the version of `react-router-dom` is 6 then downgrade it to 5 thats where error comes from.

I know this because now `npm install` install version 6 as its default version but the tutorials and knowledge about react router on line is still for version 5.

so on your package.json change version from `6` to `5.3.0` and run `npm install` on your terminal

Comment: thanks a lot that did the job ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Since the route tag is empty, you aren't returning anything. You need to pass the path and the component that should be rendered for each path.
In this case considering you have a single path and want to show Hello World!! when the app starts, you should add

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

This will render your App component when you start the app. You can add other components for other routes similarly.

Comment: I have already tried that but with a different syntax like this "<Route path=" /login"> <Login/> </Route> after of course importing the previously mentioned component but the content also didn't appear, i will try the syntax you provided dear sir ^_^

Comment: just look to your package.json if the version of `react-router-dom` is 6 then thats is a problem, because the codes you're writing is for version 5 and below. check that and let me know

Comment: @ndotie yes sir the react-router-dom is 6. can you please tell me what to do

Comment: check my answer above i've told you what to do

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to do :
a) in react-router-dom v6 **Route** element should be inside **Routes** element.
b) instead of **component** attribute you will have **element** attribute
c) element attribute should contain jsx like below

```
<Routes>
   <Route exact path="/" element={
      <>
        <SomeComponent></SomeComponent>
        <SomeOtherComponent></SomeOtherComponent>
      </>
    }>
    </Route>
    <Route path='/other_address' element={<OtherComponent />}></Route>
</Routes>
```